# iOS Networking - Moya & Protocol Buffer Serialisation

Tags: ios, json, swift, protocol-buffers, moya

Can anyone elaborate me on the possibility of using Moya for communicating with web services that use ProtoBuf Serialisation instead of JSON notation? Is it possible? Is it already implemented or is there any extensions for it?
Any information is really appreciated :)

Comment: I don't think Moya supports protobuf. You probably will receive raw data from web service, and then just use this library: https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf to create your proto object from it.

Comment: @vpoltave Yeah, But is it possible (in theory) to integrate those so that Moya can use swift-protobuf for serialisation/deserialisation?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it is possible**

Here is the process how you can use protobuf with Moya.

```
import Foundation
import Moya
import SwiftProtobuf


 enum Currency {
   case exchangeRate(param: SwiftProtobuf.Message)
 }

 extension Currency: TargetType {

     var validationType: ValidationType {
    
         return .successCodes
     }

     var headers: [String: String]? {
   
         return [
           "Accept":        "application/octet-stream",
           "Content-Type":  "application/octet-stream",
           "Authorization": [use auth token here if any],
          ]
       }

     var baseURL: URL {
        
         return  URL(string:"https:www.currency.com")
     }

    var path: String {
       switch self {

         case .exchangeRate:

          return "/exchangeRate"
        }
     }

    var method: Moya.Method {
       switch self {

          case .exchangeRate:

           return .post
        }
     }

    var parameters: Data? {
        switch self {

          case let .exchangeRate(param):

           return try! param.serializedData()
        }
      }

   var task: Task {
        switch self {

           case .exchangeRate:

            return .requestData(self.parameters!)    
         }
       }
    }
```

You can access an API like this:

```
     provider = MoyaProvider<GitHub>()
     provider.request(.exchangeRate(param:[here will be protobuf model object])) {                
          result in
         switch result {
            case let .success(moyaResponse):
              //do something with the response data
            case let .failure(error):
              //error occured
            }
       }
```